# Does a phrase "to support needs" sound natural?

Tags: word-request

Please, help me to put a proper word collocation into a sentence.

I need to describe in an office announcement that a new printer is set for satisfy any employee (printing) need.

I found the phrase *"to support needs"*, but I am not sure about it.

The context is here:

> Dear Colleagues,
>
> We would like to inform you that the new printer is now available on the 9th floor of the 3rd tower. It was set to simplify the access to the printer and support needs of the growing number of employees of the recently opened floors of the third tower.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: **needs of *the* growing number of employees on the ...**

Comment: If as you have said the new printer warrants a little fanfare, rather than going over formal could you use a little humour instead. As many have requested The new printer has arrived and is setup on the 9th Floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The printer is available for use by all employees.

If you want to use that phrase you've found:

> The printer was set up  on the 9th floor *to support the needs* of a growing number of employees...

You could say *placed* instead of *set up*.

Comment: But is that phrase makes sense at all?

Comment: Yes, that phrase does make sense.  It is a common collocation. In context it is understood to refer to the printing needs. You could also say **address the needs**.

Comment: or **meet the needs**

Answer (score 1):

OP's text is not a good example of clear concise English, so ELL users are advised *not* to imitate the excessively verbose phrasing.

It's badly-written for many reasons - one of which is that the specific words causing OP's confusion are *syntactically ambiguous* (though it would be stretching a point to claim that this leads to any meaningful *semantic* ambiguity).

The new printer ***was set to*** [do certain things] - which I assume is a clumsy way of saying it was ***set up = configured***, but feasibly he actually meant ***set in position / placed*** [on the 9th floor].

The printer was set [up] with two objectives - the first of which is ***to simplify the access to the printer***. But the *second* purpose is unclear - it's syntactically ambiguous whether purpose #2 is

> (a) *to simplify [the] access to [the] support needs [of blah blah]*
>    (b) *to simplify [the] support needs [of blah blah]*
>    (c) *to support [the] needs [of blah blah]*

Note that in (a) and (b) above, ***support*** is an *adjective* - they're "needs" of the type associated with "[technical] support". But in (c) it's a *verb* - provide assistance to deal with those "needs". Also note that as indicated by the square brackets littering my examples, many of those definite articles are "optional" (and stylistically, *most* of them would be better discarded).

---

Much more direct and to the point would be, for example,...

> *It was set [up] **for** the growing number of employees <strike>of</strike> on the recently opened floors of the third tower.*

Even more direct, and discarding information that's unnecessary and/or irrelevant...

> *There is a new printer on the 9th floor of the 3rd tower.*

Comment: Actually the writer is me; it was the sentence draft for the phrase I am not sure with to put in. But I appreciate your explanation of those mistakes. 
I just need to underpin setting the printer that is why those *objectives*: **to simplify the access** and **to support needs**.
So what do you think - is there a possibility to put it in the sentence avoiding it to sound clumsy?

Comment: Ooops! No offence intended! But is it *really* necessary for you to explain in such detail exactly why you're adding (or relocating) a shared printer? And who cares that *[you] **would like to inform** [those reading your email]* that there's a new printer? Why not just say ***There is a new printer on the 9th floor of the 3rd tower*** and leave it at that? I'm sure all those people you're emailing have better things to do with their time than read all the irrelevant additional details.

Comment: I've worked in organizations where a printer has been wanted by all but was a long time in coming.  So a new printer can be a big deal. There are times when one needs to be accompanied by a little fanfare.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Perhaps the new printer's first job could be to print hundreds of full-colour glossy flyers for distribution throughout the organisation! Or go the whole hog and print *thousands* of flyers, for distribution among the local populace!

Comment: Yes, as  *Tᴚoɯɐuo* has mentioned it is like a big deal, because the new floors are opened and they are waiting for that printer. Also it has to be the announcement on the company's site, so it should be written in a polite formal way.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I was thinking there might be some happy medium somewhere between a curt "There's a new printer on the 9th floor available to all" and 76 trombones and a big parade. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODu888i14-I

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I was always being taken to task for writing too long / too many emails in contexts like this, so perhaps my position now is a bit stronger than most. But (and it's eating me up that I can't typographically illustrate my point in a comment here) perhaps the best "readers' time-saving" alternative to ***76 trombones and a big parade*** would be to just send my proposed brief notification ***in a 76-point typeface**!* :)

Comment: @Gamilato I am sorry I agree with fumblefingers this sentence is un-recoverable. It needs scrapping and starting again.

Answer (score 1):

Call me an old cynic but if I read that something is being done "to support needs", I understand that "they" are not proposing to meet or satisfy needs but merely to "support" them. In ordinary English "needs" are "met" or "satisfied" but not "supported". Hence my cynicism in this case: it is a new printer but not as big or pretty or as efficient as is really required.

Cynic or not, I used to be an official in a Finance Ministry and a good rule of thumb was to translate "needs" as "demands" because generally speaking those demanding something greatly outnumber those who actually need it.

My conclusion is, given that the OP says that the phrase is his/her own, that  wording along the lines of "... and meet the increased demands of ..." would evoke less cynicism.